# Create notify trigger for specific JSON value in inserted row

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I have a table with event entity

```
create table event_entity
(
    id           varchar(36) not null
        constraint constraint_4
            primary key,
    details_json varchar(2550),
    event_time   bigint,
    type         varchar(255),
    user_id      varchar(255)
);
```

`details_json` has such data:

```
    {
   "custom_required_action":"VERIFY_EMAIL",
}
```

I need to create a trigger and notify on inserted row `event_entity` table with condition:

```
WHERE type = 'CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION' AND details_json:custom_required_action = 'VERIFY_EMAIL'
```

I've made it with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_verifyEmail()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(
            'verifyEmail',
            row_to_json(NEW)::text);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER notify_verifyEmail
    AFTER INSERT ON event_entity
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (new.type = 'CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_verifyEmail();
```

But how to add second condition with `details_json` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the notification trigger function. In the example below it will notify on `the_notification_channel` and have the new row values JSON formatted as notification payload. The names of the trigger, the trigger function and the notification channel are such for illustration only.

```sql
create or replace function the_notification_trigger_function()
returns trigger language plpgsql as 
$$
begin
 perform pg_notify('the_notification_channel', to_json(new)::text);
 return null;
end;
$$;
```

and then create the trigger with a condition

```sql
create trigger the_notification_trigger
after insert on event_entity for each row
when new.type = 'CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION' 
 and new.details_json::json ->> 'custom_required_action' = 'VERIFY_EMAIL'
execute function the_notification_trigger_function();
```

Unrelated but it would be much better if your `details_json` field was of type `jsonb` instead of text and `event_time` was of type `timestamp` instead of `bigint`. What is `constraint_4`?

It might be a good idea to move the `new.details_json::json ->> 'custom_required_action' = 'VERIFY_EMAIL'` sub-condition *into* the trigger function so that the trigger fill fire on every `'CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION'` and the function would decide on how to react.

Comment: Somehow it didn't work with 'perform pg_notify'. Was error Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_notify(unknown, event_entity) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function the_notification_trigger_function() line 3 at PERFORM

Comment: Worked like that  NOTIFY the_notification_channel, '123'; But how to implement to_json(new) here?

Comment: My omission. pg_notify expects 2 text arguments. So the second ome (JSON) shall be cast to text. `pg_notify('the_notification_channel', to_json(new)::text)`

Comment: Regarding types and constraint, I ain't control that, it is keycloak's DDL.

Comment: I see. Have to live with it.

Comment: With json condition I have an error Unable to resolve column 'custom_required_action' . Should I add quotes like and new.details_json::json ->> 'custom_required_action' = 'VERIFY_EMAIL'

Comment: Of course. Sorry, I am missing so many things this morning. Answer updated.

Comment: No problem, figured that!

Answer (score 1):

can u try with below once and let me if it works

```
 CREATE TRIGGER notify_verifyEmail
        AFTER INSERT ON event_entity
        FOR EACH ROW 
        WHEN (new.type = 'CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION' AND (new.details_json->>'custom_required_action') = 'VERIFY_EMAIL')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_verifyEmail();
```